Как установить приложение на телефон
Купил телефон недавно, Инфиникс, андроид 11. Нужно установить приложение
не из play маркета. Скачал apk архив, распаковал, а там ни одного exeшника, пробовал менять формат apk на exe - установщик посылает. Как его установить? Может скомпилировать надо как-нибудь или пересобрать? У друзей спрашиваю, а они пальцем у виска крутят и смотрят как на дауна.

А пробовали ли вы запустить непосредственно APK файл?)

Нет, я думал это архив. Спасибо, все получилось!

@ЭльдарГатин друзья не любят помогать, похоже вы где-то им задолжали))
